# In capistrano3 can you change the symlink destination when using the linked_files directive?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

e.g. create a symlink vi deploy.rb

```
set :linked_files, %w{path/to/shared/file}
```

change the symlink destination using something like ...

```
set :linked_files, {'path/to/shared/file' => 'destination/path'}
```

Answer (score 1):

no, write your own task

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :create_symlink do
        on roles(:web) do
            execute "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/prod/config.php #{deploy_to}/current/config.php"
        end
    end
end
after :deploy, "deploy:create_symlink"
```

[reference](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/04/10/deploying-rails-apps-part-6-writing-capistrano-tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ben's answer, I've frequently used `linked_files` verbatim, then created a symlink from shared to the final destination.

Comment: Thanks will_in_wi, but can you please add examples, as I find the ruby/capistrano documentation a little sparse.